# How to write a regex for words seperated by colon or newline & tab

Tags: regex

\w+: \w+\s*\w*\n - This is regex for combination of key-value pairs(separated by colon)  seperated by new line.

The above are two matches...
abc:sss
def:ghj

But this regex only allow first occurrence of space/tab in the word.

Could someone tell me how do I avoid "ALL" occurance of tab/space

### EDIT:

```
sports: soccer, tennis   I would like to play all kind of spots
        the spots desc continues...
Food: Indian, Italian, Mexican - I love all three.
```

If we have a text like above - If I use a regex, I need to get 2 matches.

1. Sports : Sports text
2. Food: FoodText.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you want to do? Give an sample input and your expected output

Comment: I don't see how your regexp would match that. The regexp has a required space after `:`, but your matches don't have that. BTW, you don't need to escape `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with this regex:

```
^(\w+):|(.+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG7bF2/1)**

The group 1 will capture the "keys" while group 2 will capture the content. I couldn't make that group 2 store all the content for multiple lines, so if you have  multiple lines you will have multiple group 2. Look below the match information:

Match information

```
MATCH 1
    Group 1:    [0-6]   `sports`
MATCH 2
    Group 2:    [7-63]  ` soccer, tennis   I would like to play all kind of spots`
MATCH 3
    Group 2:    [64-99] `        the spots desc continues...`
MATCH 4
    Group 1:    [100-104]   `Food`
MATCH 5
    Group 2:    [105-150]   ` Indian, Italian, Mexican - I love all three.`
```

Comment: Please see the edit. I need to get the text separated by new line with no space before the starting character.

Comment: @Relativity fixed, take a look now

Answer (score 0):

This code should work exactly, assuming all of your embedded newlines within a match are immediately followed by a tab (notice the \n\t in the pattern below).

```
//Pattern to match the form "Word: some text with embedded newline/tab combos"
const string pattern = @"^\w+:(.|(\n\t))*";

//Get the matching items
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

//Write out the matches
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----MATCH-----");
    Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

For your input string, this code's output looks like:

```
-----MATCH-----
sports: soccer, tennis   I would like to play all kind of spots
    the spots desc continues...

-----MATCH-----
Food: Indian, Italian, Mexican - I love all three.
```

Be sure not to forget the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option; it makes the `^` behave as a beginning of line, not just a beginning of the whole string.